# Tables with <tr>'s inside the <td>'s

Tags: html, arrays

this may sound stupid because in the basic html it's not possible. But is it possible to render a table like this (No, but what are my options?):

```
<table>
    <td>
        <tr>col 1 row 1</tr>
        <tr>col 1 row 2</tr>
        <tr>col 1 row 3</tr>
    </td>
    <td>
        <tr>col 2 row 1</tr>
        <tr>col 2 row 2</tr>
        <tr>col 2 row 3</tr>
    </td>
</table>
```

I really need this because I got these kind of arrays (see code below) and I can't remake them to fit the right image, because the amount of columns is always different.

```
array('col 1 row 1', 'col 1 row 2', 'col 1 row 3');
array('col 2 row 1', 'col 2 row 2', 'col 2 row 3');
```

Either a HTML as PHP solution would be helpful

Wanted outputs:

for html solutions

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1 row 1</td>
        <td>col 2 row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1 row 2</td>
        <td>col 2 row 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col 1 row 3</td>
        <td>col 2 row 3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

for php solutions

```
array('col 1 row 1', 'col 2 row 1');
array('col 1 row 2', 'col 2 row 2');
array('col 1 row 3', 'col 2 row 3');
```

Comment: why would you want `tr`'s inside of a `td`

Comment: “I can't remake them to fit the right image, because the amount of columns is always different” — you’ll have to, if you want to render them as an actual HTML table. In PHP, could you not 1. get the length of the longest column array, 2. create *n* arrays, where *n* is the length from 1, and 3. loop through each column array, and add each entry to the right row array?

Comment: Is the question: how to transpose the arrays? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Comment: You can have a `<tr>` inside a `<td>` by using a `<table>`. Also, the better way would be to refactor your array and iterate over rows.

Comment: @jmore009: I think the question is asking whether there’s any way to define a table by stating what appears in each column, rather than what appears in each row.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite, yes I can try to retrieve the amount of columns I've got. Than you suggest to something like this:
`$a=array(); foreach($columns as $i=>$column) { foreach($rows as $row) { $a[$i]=$row; } }`

Comment: YOu are probably after @Stano solution of transposing the arrays

Comment: Nested tables can take a long time to render and their structure can be really painful to debug. If you can avoid them I would. Is XML + XSLT an option?

Comment: @Fleuv: yeah, something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of struggling I decided to ask it to a senior php programmer. Who also said I had to get the array right.. But that also was the struggle.

Here is how its done.

First, I putted everything in an array:

```
array('a1','a2','a3');
array('b1','b2','b3');
```

These arrays became one array:

```
$a=array(
    array('a1','a2','a3'),
    array('b1','b2','b3'),
)
```

As second, you've to iterate through the area with some kind of magic to get the array in the right order etc.

```
foreach ($a as $i1 => $b) {
    foreach($b as $i2 => $c) {
        $result[$i2][$i1] = $c;
    }
}
```

And after the magic you should have an array with, in this case because count($b)==3 sub-arrays and within those arrays it should've, in this case because count($a)==2 items... so:

```
array(
    array('a1','b1'),
    array('a2','b2'),
    array('a3','b3'),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

According to HTML standards it's illegal syntax. The principle is simple: table > tr > td (sometimes also thead, tbody). So your code should look like this

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td>col 1 row 1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1 row 2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 1 row 3</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr><td>col 2 row 1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 2 row 2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>col 2 row 3</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Your code probably might work on most popular browsers as their engine is trying to "fix" such errors although always confront with [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You can nest the tables.  Something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>col 1 row 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1 row 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 1 row 3</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><td>col 2 row 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 2 row 2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>col 2 row 3</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Essentially the outer table has one row, and that row has one cell per array.  Each cell has one table, and that one table has one row (with one cell) per value.

Then you can create that output just by looping through the arrays.  In pseudo-code:

```
echo "<table>"
echo "<tr>"
for each array in arrays
  echo "<td>"
  echo "<table>"
    for each item in array
      echo "<tr>"
      echo "<td>"
      echo item
      echo "</td>"
      echo "</tr>"
  echo "</table>"
  echo "</td>"
echo "</td>"
echo "</table>"
```

---

As an alternative to tables in general, consider something like this:

```
<div>
  <span>col 1 row 1</span>
  <span>col 1 row 2</span>
  <span>col 1 row 3</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>col 2 row 1</span>
  <span>col 2 row 2</span>
  <span>col 2 row 3</span>
</div>
```

The pseudo-code is a bit cleaner too:

```
for each array in arrays
  echo "<div>"
  for each item in array
    echo "<span>"
    echo item
    echo "</span>"
  echo "</div>"
```

This puts the responsibility of *styling* the output into CSS, which is arguably where it belongs in this case anyway if this isn't technically *tabular* data.  The `div`s can be styled to float next to each other (it's up to you what to do if they are wider than the page... wrap to a new line of floated `div`s or push horizontally), and the `span`s can be styled to fill the width of the `div`s and stack vertically.

Comment: This what I also have thought about, but this is a little bit a dirty way of doing it.

Comment: @Fleuv: Well, perhaps using tables *at all* is dirty in this case.  Since it's not *really* "tabular data".  Outputting `div`s or `section`s and styling those would likely result in cleaner markup.  (It just may be a bit more work, if you're not fluent enough in CSS.  Which I'm not fluent enough to free-hand something like that in an answer.)  But if you *do* use tables then they need to be *valid* tables, which this is.

Comment: I totally agree, unfortunately I'm bound to the workaround of the Drupal CMS/Framework so for certain reasons I won't change the tags types. For example the sorting functionality.

Comment: @Fleuv: That's the thing with frameworks.  They're really helpful as long as you stay within their design.  Once you step outside of that design, they start to become a hindrance and it becomes a cost/benefit analysis to use the framework and fight for the outlier cases or not use the framework and implement the functionality manually.  Either way, I've updated the answer to include a CSS-based approach with cleaner markup, if it's helpful.